# Why didn't Amelia Bones lose her job at the Ministry if she was related to an Order member?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Order of the Phoenix, we are told that Amelia Bones is a high-up member of the Ministry (she was Head of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement).

We also find out (from Moody) that her deceased brother, Edgar, was a member of the Order of Phoenix.

Given Fudge's keenness to ostracize supporters and associates of Dumbledore, how did she keep her post? (I presume that she is old and many years into her job, from her appearance.) Mr Weasley was ostracized, wasn't he?

> ... but Fudge won't let him borrow so much as an empty ink bottle these days ...
>  <sub>Luna Lovegood, the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

And others were in risk of losing their jobs if they spoke up

> "Tonks and Arthur would lose their jobs at the Ministry if they started shooting their mouths off," said Sirius...
>  <sub>The Order of the Phoenix, the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

### My Question

So why didn't Amelia lose her job?

The only explanation I can offer is that, like Kingsley, her brother's involvement in the order was secret, but that raises the question of whether she knew about his involvement, and whether she was a member herself (which I seriously doubt).

Comment: Well, she was the Head of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement, which is one of the highest positions in the Ministry (arguably the highest non-political). Even if Fudge had wanted to get rid of her (which we don't know), even he wasn't so stupid as to try, considering how obviously well respected and admired she was.

Comment: Amelia Bones wasn't in the Order, didn't openly support Dumbledore, and had no living relatives who did so. Why would she be of interest to Fudge?

Comment: Mr Weasley was ostracised because he himself is an open supporter of Dumbledore. Tonks and he would lose their jobs if they themselves started shouting their mouths off. Having a family member who was loyal to Dumbledore twenty years ago is nowhere near in the same league. Madam Bones is never actually shown to exhibit any type of bias at all towards anyone; to the extent she appears at all (not that much), she's shown as an extremely fair and level-headed woman. Have you anything to imply that she was a supporter or associate of Dumbledore?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo yes, her long dead brother is much less important than for example her insistence on a fair trial for Harry and not allowing Fudge and his supporters to turn the Wizenmagot into a kangaroo court. My guess is that had Fudge succeeded in his campaign to discredit Dumbledore and co, the next person on his list would've been mme Bones. But to take on both on them at the same time would've been challenging.

Comment: @BMWurm Being respected and admired didn't save Dumbledore from being sacked from the Wizengamot. But I sort of see your point.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, but I thought that having a relative in the Order of the Phoenix was sufficient cause for Fudge to sack her. "'Dad says Fudge has made it clear that anyone who's in league with Dumbledore can clear out their desks,' said George" But yes, she is not directly associated with Dumbledore.

Comment: @HarryWeasley Dumbledore was undermining his authority and was after his job, or so Fudge believed. Amelia was just doing her job.

Comment: @BMWurm , got your point!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Amelia Bones held a high position in the Ministry

She held the position of Head of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement, which is itself a very high position.

> “Interrogators: Cornelius Oswald Fudge, Minister of Magic;
> Amelia Susan Bones, Head of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement

As noted by Cornelius in HBP, Amelia was a skilled witch and was said to have been killed by Voldemort himself. Holding a high position, being skilled in battle and having much experience in the Ministry evidently keeps you from  being fired, even if your brother was<sup>1</sup> an Order member.

### It wasn't common knowledge that Edgar Bones was an Order member

He's dead. A speculative theory but: we can assume that as Edgar Bones has been dead for some time, people may have forgotten that he was an Order member.

Also possible that this information wasn't even known when he was alive. Take Lupin for example. When he's persuading werewolves to not join Voldemort, I don't think he'll readily admit himself as an Order member, less he gets killed.

### She may not have been an open supporter of Dumbledore

That much says it. Although we don't see it, she's likely not as open about her support for Dumbledore as Arthur Weasley. Sure, Arthur wasn't fired, but he's kind of under a "blacklist" of Fudge's.

> but Fudge won't let him borrow so much as an empty ink bottle these days

---

<sup>1</sup> The fact that her brother was no longer in the land of the living supports the assumption that his involvement with the Order was likely unknown.

Comment: That last point is important, I think. Arthur *was* a known member of the Order of the Phoenix (as 'The Muggle-Born Registration Commission' in Deathly Hallows makes clear) and he wasn't fired. If known Order members weren't fired then I don't see why Bones would be.